# Print routes in an kivy app

Tags: python, maps, kivy

I am trying to print routes between different points on a map in a kivy app. So far I found these different options for printing a map and plotting markers on specific places :

- [MapView](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.mapview) : it's multi-plateform tile-based map rendering widget. The question is, is it possible to download tiles with routes already traced ? I didn't found a service to do that.
- [KivyMaps](http://relet.github.io/kivyMaps/) : displays WMS services, multi-plateform
- kivy-gmaps : integrate Google Maps into kivy, only for Android, it doesn't seem to be possible to trace routes with the API.

So did anyone succeed at printing routes on a map in kivy apps ?

Comment: Yeah,I did by interacting with the Google maps api in kivy...check out the docs on the google map api to help you out,what I couldn't do was to trace those routes on the map..

Comment: @Joeydanieldarko Well that's what I am trying to do, tracing routes on the map between several markers

Comment: Well I think you should take your time with kivy-gmaps,,,hack it well and it might be able to help you...I'm not sure the mapview can do that now,else you need to draw lines yourself using the graphic instructions